# AJAX: Error de lectura XML: etiqueta sin pareja. Se esperaba: </img>

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy cargando ajax al hacer prueba en el navegador me lanza el siguiente error:

> Error de lectura XML: etiqueta sin pareja. Se esperaba: `</img>`

Codigo de ajax alojado en script.js

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax('otrapagina.html',{

            success: function (response) {
               console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });


<!--codigo en otrapaginahtml-->

<a href="#" >
    <img src="img/mail.png" alt="Correo-e">
    <span>Correo-e</span>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <img src="img/snapchat.png" alt="Snapchat">
    <span>Snapchat</span>
</a>
<a href="#" >
    <img src="img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter">
    <span>Twitter</span>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <img src="img/mail.png" alt="Correo-e">
    <span>Correo-e</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Tienes que cerrar las etiquetas `img` como el error lo indica.

En vez de esto:

```
<img src="img/mail.png" alt="Correo-e">
```

Deberia de ser

```
<img src="img/mail.png" alt="Correo-e" />
```

O esto:

```
<img src="img/mail.png" alt="Correo-e"></img>
```

Completo:

```
<a href="#" >
    <img src="img/mail.png" alt="Correo-e" />
    <span>Correo-e</span>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <img src="img/snapchat.png" alt="Snapchat">
    <span>Snapchat</span>
</a>
<a href="#" >
    <img src="img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" />
    <span>Twitter</span>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <img src="img/mail.png" alt="Correo-e" />
    <span>Correo-e</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo era el cierre de las etiquetas, buena respuesta!

Comment: Al hacer la correciones aparece esto: contenido incorrecto tras un elemento XML del documento... alguna idea?

Comment: Deberias de crear otra pregunta porque no esta relacionado al error indicado en la pregunta inicial.

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta si te fue de utilidad con tu pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Te falta el dataType de entre mas opciones del ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "otrapagina.html",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (response) {
       console.log(response);
    }
  });
});
```

Tomado directamente de http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

> **dataType** (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>
> Type: String
>
> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string)

Osea que jQuery dedujo que se trata de un XML cuando deberia ser lo que tu quieras, con ponerle `dataType: "html",` a tu funcion ajax obtienes el html que deseas.

Comment: vale buen dato...