# Error en imagenes con el tag <img> y que pasa sólo en Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html5, firefox, navegador-web, img

Hay algunos errores en mi sitio web que se dan sólo con ciertas imágenes que están dentro del tag `<img>` . En realidad, el error **sólo sucede con el navegador Mozilla Firefox**, con los demás (Chrome, Opera, Edge) no me pasa.
Las imágenes las carga bien en *Firefox*, pero el tema es que yo hago clic derecho en la página (opción *"Inspeccionar elemento"*) para revisar la consola y allí veo algunos errores (*warnings*) y lo cual dice textualmente lo siguiente:

*"Error de análisis XML: etiqueta sin par. Se esperaba: `</img>`."*

No sé porque eso de "anáisis XML" (no tengo nada estructurado en ese lenguaje). Luego, abajo me pone la ubicación que es donde está la imagen. La imagen la tengo encerrada con un div:

`<div style="text-indent:0px;text-align:center;margin:0.7em 0 1em 0"><img data-src="GloImg/Menu.png" class="lazyload" alt=""></div>`

Que yo sepa el tag `<img>` no lleva cierre (ya me he fijado también en la página de *w3schools*). Aunque en algunos lados y buscando mi error dicen de poner la barra de cierre al final: `<img data-src="GloImg/Menu.png" class="lazyload" alt="" />`, pero no hace falta dicho cierre en *HTML5*, puede que sí en *XML*.

Como ya dije antes, lo raro es que los otros navegadores no me lo ponen como error cuando voy a inspeccionar la consola. ¿Será algo sin importancia?
La versión del **Firefox** que tengo es la *78.02*.

Comment: Ese ya lo había leído. Hice lo de AJAX, agregando dicho dataType, pero sigue igual.

Comment: Y la respuesta de Einer tampoco ayudo?

Comment: No, porque es para XML. No estaría bien poner el cierre "/" al final en la etiqueta img, ya que es HTML.

Comment: sí, cierra la etiqueta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado. Después de revisar bien el código, el problema estaba en un archivo *.js* que hace uso de AJAX y específicamente con el método **overrideMimeType()**.

Allí tenía `overrideMimeType("text/xml")` y lo cambié por `overrideMimeType("text/plain")`. Ahora no me genera ese error en Firefox, y en los otros navegadores también funciona.

Answer (score -1):

buen día.

Según lo que puedo entender del problema es que solo te lanza una advertencia con respecto al cierre de etiquetas `<img scr="myurl" alt="ejemplo" >`... Lo ideal es que sigas la sintaxis completa, para que no te salte el warning.

Te linkeo una repuesta del usuario **Einer** en la cual lo explica un poco más detallado, espero te sea de utilidad.

[Link a la respesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/92356/183242)

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: Eso sería para documentos XML, lo mío es HTML.